# Union Sets based on Intersection in Java

Tags: java, arrays, set, intersection

I am trying to union sets based on the intersection. For example:

I have a set as : { [4,5,7], [1,3,4,6], [5,6,8],[40,41],[38,40],[36,37,41] }

The result should be : { [1,3,4,7,5,8,6] ,[40,36,37,41,38] }

Note that: the first three sets have 4 and 6 as intersection. The same is applied to the last three sets where they have 40 and 41 as intersection.

I tried to iterate on the original set but can not modify it while iterating. Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Sorry, 7 should be there.

Comment: what you want to use Collection or array, and also why the result contain to sets, is not must be one set contains the union of the 6 sets?

Comment: The result contains two sets because the first two sets have an intersected number 4, and the third set has an intersected number 6 with the new  combined set (the first and the second set) . I hope you got that. The same logic is applied on the last three sets. As result, we eventually will have only two sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it .Let me know if you think it is not correct. However,  I am sharing it in case someone is looking for the answer!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;;

public class TestSet {

public static Set<Set<Integer>> origSets = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
public static Set<Set<Integer>> allSets = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 7));
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 6));
    Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 8));
    Set<Integer> set4 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(40, 41));
    Set<Integer> set5 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(38, 40));
    Set<Integer> set6 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(36, 37, 41));
    origSets.add(set1);
    origSets.add(set2);
    origSets.add(set3);
    origSets.add(set4);
    origSets.add(set5);
    origSets.add(set6);



    for (Set<Integer> eachSet : origSets) {
        processSet(eachSet);
    }
    printResult();

}

public static void processSet(Set<Integer> candi) {
    boolean flag = false;
    if (!allSets.isEmpty()) {
        for (Set<Integer> old_set : allSets) {
            Set<Integer> intersected = Sets.intersection(candi, old_set);
            if (!intersected.isEmpty()) {
                addSet(candi, old_set);
                allSets.remove(old_set);
                flag=true;
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(!flag){
            allSets.add(candi);
        }


    } else {
        allSets.add(candi);
    }

}

public static void addSet(Set<Integer> candi, Set<Integer> new_set) {
    Set<Integer> candidate = Sets.union(candi, new_set);
    allSets.add(candidate);

}

public static void printResult(){
    for(Set<Integer> eachSet :allSets){
        System.out.println(eachSet);
    }
}


  }
```

Output:

```
[38, 40, 36, 37, 41]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7]
```

The idea is to create a new empty set of sets ( we called it allSets) and feed it one set from the origSets at time ( at each time we check for intersection if so we union them and add it to the empty set(allSets).

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of modification on practitioner's [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087826/12876491).

Without using `com.google.common.collect.Sets`.

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TestSet {

    public static <T> void unionSets(Set<T> candi, Set<Set<T>> ssets) {
        boolean flag = false;
        if (!ssets.isEmpty()) {
            for (Set<T> old_set : ssets) {
                Set<T> candidate = new HashSet<>(candi);
                candidate.addAll(old_set);
                if (candidate.size() != candi.size() + old_set.size()) {
                    ssets.add(candidate);
                    ssets.remove(old_set);
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(!flag){
                ssets.add(candi);
            }
        } else {
            ssets.add(candi);
        }
    }

    public void test_it() throws Exception {
        Set<Set<Integer>> original_ssets= new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 7));
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 4, 6));
        Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 8));
        Set<Integer> set4 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(40, 41));
        Set<Integer> set5 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(38, 40));
        Set<Integer> set6 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(36, 37, 41));
        original_ssets.add(set1);
        original_ssets.add(set2);
        original_ssets.add(set3);
        original_ssets.add(set4);
        original_ssets.add(set5);
        original_ssets.add(set6);
        Set<Set<Integer>> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Set<Integer> each_set : original_ssets) {
            unionSets(each_set, result);
        }
    }
}
```